# How to display validation messages on jsp in spring mvc using redirect

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have such form

```
<form:form method="POST" action="posts/add" modelAttribute="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="author"><spring:message code="blog.posts.author.name"/></form:label></td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="author">
                        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
                        <form:options items="${authors}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="author" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="text"><spring:message code="blog.posts.text"/></form:label></td>
                <td><form:textarea path="text" rows="5" cols="30"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="text" cssClass="error" /></td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="blog.posts.save"/>" />
    </form:form>
```

and controller for it

```
@Controller
public class PostsController {

    @Autowired
    private PostDAO postDao;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @RequestMapping("/posts")
    public String showAllPosts(ModelMap model) {

        List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
        authors.add("John B.");
        authors.add("Jack C.");

        List<Post> posts = postDao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
        model.addAttribute("authors", authors);

        return "posts";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("post")
    public Post getPost(ModelMap model) {
        return new Post();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/posts/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePost(@ModelAttribute("post") Post post, BindingResult errors, ModelMap model) {

        validator.validate(post, errors);

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("posts", postDao.findAll());
            return "posts";
        }

        postDao.addPost(post);
        model.addAttribute("posts", postDao.findAll());

        return "redirect:/posts";
    }
```

I use custom validator.

It displays page with error messages in case of

```
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("posts", postDao.findAll());
                return "posts";
            }
```

I've tried to use `redirect:/posts` in return statement

but in this case it doesn't display error messages on page.

Also? I tried to add to controller. But without success.

```
@SessionAttributes("post")
```

Is it any way to redirect to page and display error messages on it?

Answer (score 4):

A redirect causes the Servlet container to respond to the client with a 302 status code and a `Location` header with the value being a URI to go to next.

Model and request attributes only exist for the lifetime of one request. So after the Servlet container sends the 302, they are gone. You need to use flash attributes. If you are using Spring 3.1+, you can do this with [`RedirectAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

Comment: I'm using spring 3.0.5. Anyway I don't clear understand what should I add to attributes

Comment: @ConstantineGladky Let's take an example. The client sends a `POST` request to `/posts/add`. You add model and request attributes and then you send a redirect to `/posts`. This will cause the server to send a 302 to the client. The client will receive this 302 and send a new GET request to `/posts`. That new request has a separate set of request attributes completely unrelated to the ones you were adding before.

Comment: yes. This doesn't cause any misunderstanding. But I'm trying to find out how can I implement it (transfer errors). What should I add to redirectAttributes, and where I should use it? As I understand I should add one more method that handles /posts and add to model what I saved in redirectAttributes?

Comment: @ConstantineGladky [Here's a Filter based implementation of flash scope](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/). Instead of adding the the model attributes, you add to session attributes. Those are persisted over many requests.

Comment: This answer should've been accepted. Similar advice from @SotiriosDelimanolis helped me resolve the same issue.